# Automatically update PivotTable data source

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Using the ole' search that stackoverflow provides, i found the following code

```
Sub Change_Pivot_Source()

Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Funnel Data Pivots").PivotTables
    pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Lead Data (Q1-Q2)")
Next pt

End Sub
```

Where "Funnel data Pivots" is my woorksheet that contains all my pivot charts i am trying to update, and "Lead Data (Q1-Q2)" is the data source of all my pivots....Each week the data source is extended (we input lines of data at the bottom, keeping the rest of the data as it is)....yet this code fails to render, saying "Reference is not valid" (on the Lead Data (Q1-Q2) line...I assumed I typod, so i changed the name in the worksheet (and in the VBA) to a much simpler text...yet it still failed.

So

A) Is this the right code I want to use to extend the data source of my pivot tables?

and

B) if it is, how do i debug it, if it's not the right code, what is?

This was my original VBA function, which updated pivot tables, but not the data source

```
Sub AllWorksheetPivots1()

Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

    pt.RefreshTable

Next pt


End Sub
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The SourceData argument requires a Range object per help, but it appears you are supplying it with a sheet name. My experience is that it actually wants a string that represents a range. So you should be using something like

```
SourceData:="Lead Data (Q1-Q2)!A1:D100"
```

But what would be even better is if you made your data a table and based your pivottable on that. Then your pivot table will automatically expand as you add new rows.